# Check to see if page exists problems

Tags: pages, oop, comparison

I've created a class to dynamically create pages. I'm checking to see if the page exists by comparing the new page's title to `post_name`. The comparison seems to work ok, but even if there is a match the page is created anyway and I can't figure out why.

My code looks like this:

```
class createDynamicPage {

public function __construct( $nameArray ) {
    $this->title = $nameArray['title']; //Title of the page
    $this->slug = $nameArray['slug']; //Page slug
}

public $pageContent = '';

public function rps_createPage(){
    $allPages = get_pages();
    $exists = false;
    foreach( $allPages as $page ){
        if( strtolower( $page->post_name ) == strtolower( $this->title ) ){
            $exists = true;
        }
    }
    if( $exisits == false ) {
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'post_title' => $this->title,
                'post_type'     => 'page',
                'post_name'  => $this->slug,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_content' => $this->pageContent,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'menu_order' => 0
            )
        );
    }
}

}

$cdArray = array( 'title' => 'Biography', 'slug' => 'concert-diary' );
$pageConcertDiary = new createDynamicPage( $cdArray );
add_action('init', array( &$pageConcertDiary, 'rps_createPage' ));
```

I assume I'm being very stupid, but I can't figure it out! Also, being a OOP newbie, I'd happy take criticism/pointers on how I've outlined the class.

Cheers

Comment: why are you querying for all pages when you can just do one for a single page with that title/slug?

Comment: @OneTrickPony - how else do I check if the page already exists other than by checking all existing pages?

Comment: just request pages with the name, ie. `$query = new WP_Query('name=concert-diary&posts_per_page=1&post_type=page');`. If you don't get any results then the page doesn't exist. But there are dedicated functions for what you're trying to achieve, like [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you comparing `$post->post_name` to `$this->title`? You should be comparing *slug* to *slug*.

Try changing your comparison from this:

```
if( strtolower( $page->post_name ) == strtolower( $this->title ) )
```

...to this:

```
if( strtolower( $page->post_name ) == strtolower( $this->slug ) )
```

Also, I might suggest keeping with the WordPress object conventions with your dynamically created pages, as doing so might help avoid such confusion.

I would change this:

```
$cdArray = array( 'title' => 'Biography', 'slug' => 'concert-diary' );
```

...to this:

```
$cdArray = array( 'title' => 'Biography', 'post_name' => 'concert-diary' );
```

And then change this:

```
public function __construct( $nameArray ) {
    $this->title = $nameArray['title']; //Title of the page
    $this->slug = $nameArray['slug']; //Page slug
}
```

...to this:

```
public function __construct( $nameArray ) {
    $this->title = $nameArray['title']; //Title of the page
    $this->post_name = $nameArray['post_name']; //Page slug
}
```

So that your comparison becomes this:

```
if( strtolower( $page->post_name ) == strtolower( $this->post_name ) )
```

That might help you avoid some confusion.

Comment: Hi @Chip - thanks for this. Makes sense of course and happily solved my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

At first, you may need to include wp-blog-header.
then use this, to check if post already exist ( you can modify it to fit pages):

```
$title = 'mytitlee';

global $wpdb;
$id_ofpost_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$title'");
$id_ofpost_title = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '$title'");
if ($id_ofpost_name || $id_ofpost_title) {echo 'Exists, here is the id:'.$id_ofpost_title.' or '.$id_ofpost_name;} 
else {echo 'post wasnt found';}
```